# dockerized ASP.NET Core website exited immediately after running/starting with exit code of 0?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I've deployed several ASP.NET Core websites and never encountered such a strange issue. I have no error returned, no sign of error except that the container just stopped.

The command looks simple like this:

```
>> docker run -it ...
>> ...
```

the next `>>` returned after a moment, no sign of error. When I checked the status of running containers with `docker ps -a`, I could see that the container I had just started exited immediately `Exited (0)`. Some questions I've found on the net are about immediate exiting as well, but it's involved console apps (without `Console.ReadLine` keeping the code from exiting). Here I've even used the flag `-it` to keep the terminal interactive.

Could you give me some suggestions to diagnose this? I'm sure something goes wrong but really if there is not any error reported, I'm just blinded and stuck. There should be no cause for an ASP.NET Core website exiting like that, unless there is some error. But in that case, the error should be returned/reported correctly?

**UPDATE**:

After trying debugging with `Docker` instead, I could find out that there are actually some errors related to SQL connection (from inside the container to the outside host). Resolving all those errors does make the container run well without premature exiting. So the problem now is why the hell the exited code could be 0? That does not make sense at all, also not even an error reported. How is that possible? Could I make something wrong (in my app code or docker configuration) for that being possible?

**UPDATE**

The dockerfile content:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["My.Web/My.Web.csproj", "My.Web/"]
RUN dotnet restore "My.Web/My.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/My.Web"
RUN dotnet build "My.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "My.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "My.Web.dll"]
```

Comment: You are trying to start/run the container using "-it" which is interactive terminal mode. 
What are you starting in this mode, are you starting a cmd/bash terminal?
Can you share the base image that you are using?
Are you using an ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile? try changing that to CMD.

Please share the Dockerfile and I can understand your issue better.

Comment: @Ashik please see my last UPDATE part, thanks for your time.

Comment: I am not able to find the base images that you've used. The latest dotnet core images (_including sdk and aspnet runtime_) are here: [microsoft-dotnet-core]( https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core).

I created a Dockerfile in a forked aspnet core example and added in github here: [dotnet-core-api](https://github.com/FAshik/dotnet-core-api/tree/master).

It uses similar Dockerfile as yours, please see [Dockerfile](https://github.com/FAshik/dotnet-core-api/blob/master/Dockerfile)

I used CMD instead of ENTRYPOINT which allows me to use -it when using `docker run` or `docker exec`.

Comment: @Ashik thanks for your care. My project targets `.NET Core 2.2` and the `Dockerfile` generated for me has `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime`, which is really strange (because the runtime required here is 2.2). So I just tried it myself by replacing `2.1` with `2.2` and it just works (pulling OK). Although it's really strange that I also could not find any such an image on the `hub.docker.com`??? Why is that? That's my concern too. Anyway the `microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime` does exist. About the `CMD` I'm not so sure if it could help log out something because I've found out ...

Comment: the cause. Actually my web app was not configured to log out to console (just to file). After configuring it to log to console as well, I could see all the error/warning/info written to the console (ENTRYPOINT is kept unchanged, of course the `-it` is always required).